# SQL Continuous Date and Values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get a continuous date and continuous investedcash from the previous effectivedate forward.  I need to pull this for the 3rd qtr of 2021, but there was no investedcash value posted on 7/1, so I need to go back to the next earliest date investedcash shows up.

The table returns this from 6/30/21 to 9/30/21.  A value only shows up when cash is actually posted to the account.

| Acctnbr | InvestedCash | EffectiveDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1315.73 | 2021-06-30 |
| 123 | 1315.74 | 2021-07-30 |
| 123 | 1340.74 | 2021-08-30 |
| 123 | 1340.75 | 2021-08-31 |
| 123 | 1349.00 | 2021-09-13 |
| 123 | 1349.84 | 2021-09-29 |
| 123 | 1349.85 | 2021-09-30 |

I need the data like this to calculate an average daily balance.  Notice it needs to be the same value each day until 7/30, then the pattern repeats until the next investedcash value on 8/30, and so on.

| Acctnbr | InvestedCash | EffectiveDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1315.73 | 6/30/2021 |
| 123 | 1315.73 | 7/1/2021 |
| 123 | 1315.73 | 7/2/2021 |
| 123 | 1315.73 | 7/3/2021 |
| 123 | 1315.73 | 7/4/2021 |
| 123 | 1315.73 | 7/5/2021 |
| 123 | 1315.73 | 7/6/2021 |
| 123 | 1315.73 | 7/7/2021 |
| 123 | 1315.73 | 7/8/2021 |
| 123 | 1315.73 | 7/9/2021 |
| 123 | 1315.73 | 7/10/2021 |
| 123 | 1315.73 | 7/11/2021 |
| 123 | 1315.73 | 7/12/2021 |
| 123 | 1315.73 | 7/13/2021 |
| 123 | 1315.73 | 7/14/2021 |
| 123 | 1315.73 | 7/15/2021 |
| 123 | 1315.73 | 7/16/2021 |
| 123 | 1315.73 | 7/17/2021 |
| 123 | 1315.73 | 7/18/2021 |
| 123 | 1315.73 | 7/19/2021 |
| 123 | 1315.73 | 7/20/2021 |
| 123 | 1315.73 | 7/21/2021 |
| 123 | 1315.73 | 7/22/2021 |
| 123 | 1315.73 | 7/23/2021 |
| 123 | 1315.73 | 7/24/2021 |
| 123 | 1315.73 | 7/25/2021 |
| 123 | 1315.73 | 7/26/2021 |
| 123 | 1315.73 | 7/27/2021 |
| 123 | 1315.73 | 7/28/2021 |
| 123 | 1315.73 | 7/29/2021 |
| 123 | 1315.74 | 7/30/2021 |
| 123 | 1315.74 | 8/1/2021 |

I can get the continuous date by using this, but not sure how to link this with the rest of it.

```
    DECLARE @startdate  date = '20210701'
DECLARE @enddate    date = '20210930'


;WITH Dates AS
     (SELECT convert(date, @startdate) as Date
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, Date)
        FROM Dates 
       WHERE DATEADD(day, 1, Date) <= @enddate

)
SELECT DATE
FROM DATES
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it easier to do this by first deriving an ExpiryDate for the records, and then using a join (to DATES) with BETWEEN condition, like this:

```
With Dates AS
(SELECT convert(date, @startdate) as Date
 UNION ALL
 SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, Date)
 FROM Dates 
 WHERE DATEADD(day, 1, Date) <= @enddate
),
MtblTV as /* Time-variant data; add ExpiryDate */
(
    select T.*, 
          ExpiryDate=dateadd(day, -1, 
                       LEAD(EffectiveDate, 1, '3000-12-31') 
                            over (partition by AcctNbr 
                                  order by EffectiveDate asc))
    from MyTbl T
) 
select *
from Dates D
     inner join
     MtblTV T
     on D.Date between T.EffectiveDate and T.ExpiryDate
order by date
```

3000-12-31 is just a dummy value to indicate that this record has not expired, yet.